# Question about importing python modules/packages in python

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

so the way I understood it, I can define a function inside a module, save it, and then import the function in a different script using "from module1 import function1". I can even create a package by saving a bunch of modules inside a package along with **init**.py to call a module using "from package1.module1 import function 1" That all makes sense to me.

However, I was looking at the keras documentation and, they have something like this:

---

import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))

x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs))

---

The second line implies that "keras" is a module script with the function Input written inside it, while the third line implies that "keras" is actually a package that contains a module called "layers" which contains the function "Dense".

I tried creating a package and module with the same name on my computer, but of course, python wouldn't let me import both ( it would only let me import the package).

Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: You can "export" things in `__init__.py` so that they can be imported by the name of the package.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I found a useful link to explain this. Thanks!

https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/510ce9456a0429f616baa243d1de3dbf